# Trouble installing Eclipse CHe locally

Tags: installation, eclipse-che

Could not install eclipse che locally on my system.

[image: Error message]

Please help me.

Comment: please tell us what error occours so we can help with a specific problem. Also look at the guidelines how to ask a question at stack overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: [Don't paste images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/13860)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at these issues [1] [2] it might help.
Basically as workaround try to run `chectl` from the directory it is installed.

- [1] https://github.com/eclipse/che/issues/15225
- [2] https://github.com/eclipse/che/issues/15482